# "update_post_meta" not working in "wp_insert_post_data" hook

Tags: post-meta

I have created the following hook in my `functions.php`

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'ad_change_title');
function ad_change_title($data)
{
    if($data['post_type'] != 'ad_listing')
        return $data;
    if(!is_admin())
        return $data;

    global $post;   
    update_post_meta((int)$post->ID, 'cp_entitle_englishel', (string)$_POST['qtrans_title_en']);

    return $data;
}
```

but the `update_post_meta` part. I have checked the `post_id`, `cp_entitle_englishel`, `qtrans_title_en` values, and they are valid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your code in current form:

1. `wp_insert_post_data` hook runs before the actual insertion happens. In other words post might not not exist yet.
2. Data in this hook does not contain `post_id`.

More fitting hooks to use are those after post insertion is processed:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to save the whole post, just update the custom field. "ad_change_title" function contains some other actions that I didn't mention, in order to keep the code simple and clear.

Comment: I also corrected the post_id thing in question's code.

Comment: @ktsixit whatever you want to modify in post doesn't change the fact that the hook you are trying to use is not appropriate. There simply might be no post to work with at that point.

Comment: eventually I had to add two different hooks, one for the post_title and one for the custom field. Thank you for your suggestions